# gdal_translate- limit memory usage

Tags: gdal-translate

I am using gdal_translate to clip raster data (using `-srcwin` and `-projwin`).
This works fine for me until I'm trying to run some concurrent processes of this command.

In this case I get random error massages of "Out Of Memory in InitBlockInfo()".
When profiling a single process it's seems that the memory usage is strongly increasing just before the end of the output file writing.

I have tried to change the GDAL_CACHEMAX config (both as environment variable and as `--config` parameter) but it seems to affect only the process until the last phase (if at all) in which its memory usage is highly increasing.

Is there a way to control this behavior?

Some Tech Details:
My version is 1.11.1 and I'm clipping wms xml layer to GTiff tiles (without compression or additional creation options).
The process memory size is reaching about 1.6gb at the last phase (also when I limit the GDAL_MAXCACHE to 64), when I clip a tiles of about 10,000 X 10,000 pixels (total mem size on my computer is 6GB)

Comment: Perhaps memory is needed for writing data into the outputfile. What is your outputformat? If it is GeoTIFF, do you write tiled GeoTIFF out (-co TILED=YES)? Or better than ask one detail at a time, add gdalinfo about your source image and complete gdal_translate command to your question.

Comment: Did you try using a more recent gdal version? 1.11.1 is from September 2014 ... Try the Latest Stable Release from June 2017 (2.2.1) ... https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/DownloadSource